# ggseasonplot in R, using only certain years

Tags: r, time-series

I am using R to analyse a time series - I am doing a ggseason plot and I have rainfall data by quarter for 50 years. 
I only want to plot every 10th year, is this possible?

At the moment I have:

```
ggseasonplot(TSAuckalandRainfall, year.labels=TRUE, year.labels.left=TRUE) + ylab("Auckland Rainfall") + ggtitle("Seasonal plot of Auckland rainfall")
```

And what I want is for a set of about 5 years, i.e say 1970, 1980, 1990, 2000, 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Use dplyr to filter the data before you do the plot.

```
require(dplyr)
decadal<-annual %>% 
  filter(
year = 1970 | 
year = 1980 |
year = 1990 |
year = 2000 |
year = 2010 |
year = 2020 
)
```

## (code not run)